# How to use a variable defined by $_POST across multiple php files?

Tags: php, android, session, post, cookies

I need to be able to use a variable, $email, that has been entered by a user in my android application, in a different php file.

loginUser.php

```
<?php
require_once('dbConnectAppside.php');
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = stripsslashes($email);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
?>
```

loginUser2.php

```
<?php
include('loginUser.php');

echo "Welcome".$email; 
?>
```

From what I have looked at online, utilizing `include()`, I should be able to use loginUser.php's variables as if they were part of *loginUser2.php*. Obviously, this not working has something to do with the `$_POST` because the error I get is

> "Undefined index email line 2 of loginUser.php"

. What I'm assuming is because nothing posted while in *loginUser2.php*, this is why it fails. My question is how do I do this logic, but correctly? I must have the `$_POST` line because it's how my android app gives the php file users' entered email.

Additionally, I have attempted using `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` but I think I'm running into the same problem because I reference variables that are being defined by a `$_POST` command which happen earlier. That or I'm not using `$_SESSION` and/or `$_COOKIE` correctly.

Comment: -utilizing include(), I should be able to use loginUser.php's variables as if they were part of loginUser2.php.

Its not like that. All the variables & methods of loginUser.php are available in loginUser2.php "asif they are declared in loginUser2.php". Its just like you are defining the variables in the file, not like an object.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm also having trouble because since I am using an app, each of these pages is accessed individually. It's not like in HTML where each form can carry over the cookie or session on a page reload. I need the above to work as if they are completely separate from each other, or have an explained answer as to alternatives.